# Issue on Camel route - parsing XML tags

Tags: xpath, junit, apache-camel

I have a complex camel route, which starts with an initialization route, which tries to set the headers with the info from the XML used as input.

I wonder how the route is not being able to parse the XML content, using XPath.

Before calling the route, I print the xml information in my java JUNIT, and it prints correctly, with all xml tags.

So I know the information is being sent as I am expecting.

But that route, which should set the headers using XPath, returns  empty to any expression I try to use! I even used a XPath tool to assist me (https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester), to check if was some xpath coding mistake, but I get the results I want from there.

So, let's suppose, I have an XML as:

```
<bic:Test>
    <bic:context>       
            <bic:memberCode>GOOGLE</bic:memberCode>
    </bic:context>
</bic:Test>
```

So, with the line below:

```
<setHeader headerName="myHeader">
                <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//<anyTag>/text()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

or

```
<setHeader headerName="myHeader">
                <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//<anyTag></xpath>
</setHeader>
```

I will see the header with empty content.

I tried so many different things, that finally I decided to print the all the content, using an XPath expression as /.

It will print only the content ("GOOGLE"), not the tags.

Could you please assist me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a namespace related issue.
You have to define the bic namespace in the  camel context and then use it in the xpath expression.

Have a look at the documentation in https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/xpath-language.adoc and particularly in the example of "Using XML configuration"

Also look at "Namespace auditing to aid debugging" for further information about debugging namespace related issues in camel.

Comment: Indeed there was a misspelling in the namespace declaration. 
Very useful link. Thank you a lot!